# How do you print an array of strings in MIPS?

Tags: arrays, assembly, printing, mips

I'm having an array of strings and I want to print them out. Here's currently what I have:

```
data: .asciiz "foo", "bar", "hello", "elephant"...(16 of these strings)
size: .word 16


    move $s0, $zero # i = 0
    la $s1, data # load array
    la $s2, size #load size
print_array:


bge $s0, $s2, exit # i >= size -> exit

la $a0, 0($s1) #load the string into a0
li $v0, 4 #print string
syscall

addi $s0, $s0, 1 # i++
addi $s1, $s1, 4

j print_array

exit:
    jr $ra
```

I know this won't work because li $v0, 4 is for printing strings only. I am not sure what to do next from here...

Comment: That's not an array of strings, that's one long string.  You haven't recorded the start-address of the separate words anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

That's not an array of strings, that's one long string.  You haven't recorded the start-address of the separate words anywhere.

Another array holding addresses would make it possible to loop over it.

```
.section .rodata

data1: .asciz "foo"
data2: .asciz "bar"
data3: .asciz "hello"
data4: .asciz "elephant"
# ...(16 of these strings)

array_of_strings:
    .word data1, data2, data3, data4, ...
    .word 0      // NULL-terminate the list if you want, instead of using the end-address
array_of_strings_end:

# Or calculate the size at assemble time (/4 to scale by the word size, so it's an element count not a byte count)
# storing the size in memory is pointless, though; make it an assemble-time constant with .equ

.equ size, (array_of_strings_end - array_of_strings)/4
```

Also note that it's `.asciz`, not `.asciiz`.

Answer (score -2):

Try using `.ascii` directive so it doesn't put a null character at the end of your string.

Comment: How does that actually help, though?  It's still one giant string with no pointers to the separate words.  And doesn't the string-print system call in this MIPS simulator takes a 0-terminated string instead of a pointer+length?  In that case, having all the words packed together with no separators would be unusable even if you had pointers to them.