# Printing arrays of strings in MIPS

Tags: arrays, mips

I'm working on a program that's supposed to accept input (numbers 1-9) from the user, and then use that input to print completed MIPS instructions (with 1 = add, 2 = addi, 3 = or, etc.).

An example of this would be that the user inputs the number 1, and the program outputs "`add $t2, $t0, $t1`". The user inputs the number 2, and the program outputs "`addi $t3, $t2, 100`" (the registers are both consecutive and linked).

So, as seen above, one function of the program is to iterate through registers `$t0-$t9` as the user inputs numbers. I thought that the best way to print out these registers along with their associated opcode would be to put them in an array and cycle through them. However, I can't find out if/how MIPS prints out arrays of strings (and yes, I saw the other stackoverflow post asking the same question, but I don't quite understand the answer because it's written in C).

I would really appreciate any help people are able to give!

This is the relevant part of my code (I know it's not much, sorry):

```
.data
registers: .asciiz "$t1", "$t2", "$t3", "$t4", "$t5", "$t6", "$t7", "$t8", "$t9"  #this is the array that I want to print
registerSize: .word 9

.text 
readOpcodes:    #read the user-entered ints (1-9) in preparation for numberDecisions
add $t0, $t0, $zero
lb $s0, opcodes($t0)

numberDecisions:    #decide which instruction to output based on user input
beq $s0, 1, addOpcode 
beq $s0, 2, addiOpcode 
beq $s0, 3, orOpcode 
beq $s0, 4, oriOpcode
beq $s0, 5, lwOpcode
beq $s0, 6, swOpcode
beq $s0, 7, jOpcode
beq $s0, 8, beqOpcode
beq $s0, 9, bneOpcode 

registerAllocation: #this is all I've really got when it comes to printing out the register array
addi $s1, $zero, 0  #register counter = 0
la $s2, registers   #load register array in $s2
la $s3, registerSize    #load register array size into $s3

addOpcode:
li $v0, 4   #print 'add' opcode
la $a0, addPrint
syscall

addi $t0, $t0, 1
beq $t0, 5, end
j readOpcodes    #Ideally, I'd be able to print the registers (in the proper order depending on the opcode, obviously) in this section for each opcode

addiOpcode:  #feel free to ignore the rest; it's just the process of printing all 9 opcodes. Sorry if it's not completely relevant, but I wasn't sure how clear my code would be if I left it all out
li $v0, 4   #print 'addi' opcode
la $a0, addiPrint
syscall

addi $t0, $t0, 1
beq $t0, 5, end
j readOpcodes

orOpcode:
li $v0, 4   #print 'or' opcode
la $a0, orPrint
syscall

addi $t0, $t0, 1
beq $t0, 5, end
j readOpcodes

oriOpcode:
li $v0, 4   #print 'ori' opcode
la $a0, oriPrint
syscall

addi $t0, $t0, 1
beq $t0, 5, end
j readOpcodes

lwOpcode:
li $v0, 4   #print 'lw' opcode
la $a0, lwPrint
syscall

addi $t0, $t0, 1
beq $t0, 5, end
j readOpcodes 

swOpcode:
li $v0, 4   #print 'sw' opcode
la $a0, swPrint
syscall

addi $t0, $t0, 1
beq $t0, 5, end
j readOpcodes

jOpcode:
li $v0, 4   #print 'j' opcode
la $a0, jPrint
syscall

addi $t0, $t0, 1
beq $t0, 5, end
j readOpcodes

beqOpcode:
li $v0, 4   #print 'beq' opcode
la $a0, beqPrint
syscall

addi $t0, $t0, 1
beq $t0, 5, end
j readOpcodes

bneOpcode:
li $v0, 4   #print 'bne' opcode
la $a0, bnePrint
syscall 

addi $t0, $t0, 1
beq $t0, 5, end
j readOpcodes

end: 
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Comment: To print String  have you tried `li $v0,4`? Also you might also need an array to store each and every output you want to print. You might have to use `.space` to allocate bytes for your array!

Comment: I tried something similar to the code entered by the user here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26198491/how-do-you-print-an-array-of-strings-in-mips), but I just got an error message

Comment: try `la $a0,"nameOfString"` and then `li $v0,4` and `syscall`

Comment: I end up with the error message "line 77 column 1: "la": Too few or incorrectly formatted operands. Expected: la $t1,($t2)"

Comment: adding the parenthesis?What happens when you add them? I think that since it's a string it has to print it. It's not characters to use a for loop or something like that in order to print each and every char

Comment: I really have no idea-- every variation with la and "nameOfString" I've tried so far has resulted in an error code